# How can I implement in Rails bid offers that sellers can cancel or accept within 24hrs or transaction is cancelled?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a marketplace in rails that allows buyers to make an offer to the seller as a bid for a listing. The seller can cancel or accept the bid but only has a 24 hr window to do this or the bid expires and the transaction is cancelled. A user can be both a buyer or a seller.

I have an Order model that represents each transaction.

```
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :listing
end
```

On my reservation controller,
    Class OrdersController < Application Controller
        before_action :authenticate_user!

```
def create 
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @seller = @order.listing.user
    @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @order.seller_id = @seller.id
    @bidding_fee = @order.bidding_fee
end
```

I want to differentiate between a buyer cancel and seller cancel because if a seller cancels a bid for a listing  the buyer pays no bidding fee but if the buyer cancels the order he made he is charged a bidding fee. How can the transactions for bids be implemented. The hardest part is figuring out creating a timer in rails that will show the seller how much time is left e.g 4 hrs 12 min before the bid expires and cancelling the bid after 24 hrs if there's no response especially keeping in mind different client side time zones that may be hours apart from the created_at time of the order. I also need to show order status as pending, canceled or accepted which rules out boolean functionality because that creates three possible statuses. Any kind of help in any of these problems would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might have noticed that in `bids` table (I am assuming the table name) there is a field called `created_at`. You can use this as the `start-time` indicator.

In `bids` page where you show all the bids to `seller`. Either you can

- only show the valid bids (`bids.where('bids.created_at > ?', 24.hours.ago)`)
- Or, show all the `bids` but disable the bids created before `24 Hours`

---

Better way would be keeping track of the status of the bid with `status` attribute. To invalidate a `bid` after 24Hours you can use background processors like `sidekiq`, `resque`.

For example: With `Sidekiq`

```
BidInvalidator.perform_in(24.hours, 'mike', 1)
BidInvalidator.perform_at(24.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1)
```

---

**Update**

> Do you know how to check the time on the client side based on the
>   timezone of the created_at timestamp on the database if you take into
>   account some users may make an offer before the created_at time if
>   they live 6hrs behind in Alaska?

Well, ActiveRecord stores all date-time in UTC time so that developers can converted it to any timezone you like.

You need to set `TimeXone` according to user's timezone. You can store `timezone offset` in browser cookie and get the `offset` to calculate the `timezone` in Server side.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!($.cookie('time_zone'))) {
    current_time = new Date();
    expired_after_days = 365;
    $.cookie('time_zone', current_time.getTimezoneOffset(), { path: '/', expires: expired_after_days } );
    // Here expired_after_days represents the number of days the cookies will store the info
  }
})
```

in `application_controller` you can

```
  # setting the time zone with the current time zone offset
  before_filter :set_time_zone
  def set_time_zone
    time_zone_offset = cookies[:time_zone].to_i
    Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-time_zone_offset.minutes]
  end
```

**Note**: `Time.zone` is thread safe.

Now [you need to use `DateTime.current` in place of `DateTime.now`](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/ruby-on-rails-date-today-differs-from-date-current/)

> Does it provide functionality to create a worker that checks the
>   status attribute a little more frequently like every ten minutes.If a
>   bid is cancelled Immediately I don't want to have to wait 24hrs before
>   informing a buyer the bid is cancelled

Well to execute tasks in specific point of time you can create cronjobs using [`Whenever gem`](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Do you know how to check the time on the client side based on the timezone of the created_at timestamp on the  database if you take into account some users may make an offer before the created_at time if they live 6hrs behind in Alaska And I haven't used sidekiq before. Does it provide functionality to create a worker that checks the status attribute a little more frequently like every ten minutes.If a bid is cancelled Immediately I don't want to have to wait 24hrs before informing a buyer the bid is cancelled.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation was really helpful in showing how to coincide the client side and database timezone.

Comment: My Pleasure; Is there any thing else I can do to help you solve this problem Wil?

Comment: Im having trouble figuring out the best way to implement a cancel button once a bid has been accepted. It's important that the app knows who cancelled the order because if the seller cancels, no bidding fee is charged but if the buyer cancels there is a bidding fee. I cant go with a delete action because if I delete the order I wont know who canceled the order. Don't know if i need an ajax post action to update a seller_cancel attribute&status attribute of the Order model or use an  edit form  ,which would be weird because the only thing the user does is submit the cancel submit button.

Comment: Make sure you are not going out of the context of the question; It would be great if you create a separate question. It will draw attentions to other contributors and also will help to other developers having similar problems

Comment: Okay,will put it in another question

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need a timer. You just need the time until the bid is valid. I guess you will have some kind of `Bit` model. When a bit is created by a buyer store when the bid expires in a `expires_at` column:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_expired_at

  private
  def set_expired_at
    self.expired_at = Time.current + 24.hour
  end
end
```

This allows you to add an `expired?` method to the same class which you could use in the view to decide if you want to still list an offer:

```
def expired?
  expired_at < Time.current
end
```

Or you could add a scope to only load unexpired bits:

```
scope :unexpired, -> { where('expired_at < ?', Time.current) }
```

If an offer is pending or was excepted could be implemented as a simple `accepted` boolean in the database. Which lead to the following `status` method:

```
def status
  if accepted?
    'accepted'
  else
    expired? ? 'expired' : 'pending'
  end
end
```

Since all this methods a depending on the current time, there is no need for an external timer, a cron job or a background job. The model it self is always able to return the current state.

Comment: Thanks Spickermann, I don't have a bid model. I added my model in the question. Is there a reason why you are using Time.current instead of Time.now? I want to be able to check the users timezone against the time of created_at timestamp. Do you know how to achieve this considering different global timezones.

Comment: Your `Order` model looks basically like the `Bit` model I was thinking of. Just add a `expired_at` datetime and `accepted` boolean column to your `Order` model.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your last bit of code which I'm assuming you put in the model. Where are you calling accepted from? Once an order is created I want the seller to have a  Cancel and a Accept button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `delayed_job`, `sidekiq` or `resque` or similar tools to schedule your function to be called as soon as the bid is created. And when 24 hour is up, when the function get's called you can check there if it was accepted or not.

Comment: Thanks Alfie. I am looking for something more responsive. I don't want users to wait for twenty four hours to find out if a bid was accepted or not. I want to check the status at least every ten minutes.